# Kill a sudo/root process with pexpect

Tags: python, python-2.7, pexpect

Given a pexpect spawned process that's opened with sudo, like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pexpect

cmd = ['sudo', 'bash', '-c', '"some long-running sudo command"']
cmd = ' '.join(cmd)
child = pexpect.spawn(cmd, timeout=60)

i = child.expect([
  'success',
  'error'])
if i == 0:
  print('ok')
else:
  print('fail')
  # insert code here
```

How would I kill this process on fail (or success, for that matter)?

I've tried the following (replacing `# insert code here`):

```
child.kill(0)
child.close(force=True)
```

Both give the following error, which makes sense as *the Python script is not a root process*, and it's trying to *kill something that is a root process*.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./myscript.py", line 85, in <module>
    requires_qemu()
  File "./myscript.py", line 82, in requires_qemu
    child.close(0)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pexpect/__init__.py", line 747, in close
    raise ExceptionPexpect('Could not terminate the child.')
pexpect.ExceptionPexpect: Could not terminate the child.
```

It is not possible to run the script as root, due to file permissions (run from a shared NFS drive where root access is blocked)

Comment: `kill(0)` probably won't do anything - there's no signal 0. The common ones to terminate an unresponsive process are SIGTERM (15) and SIGKILL (9). Signal numbers are available as constants in the `signal` module.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `sudo` to kill it as root:

```
subprocess.call(['sudo', 'kill', str(child.pid)])
```

Comment: Clever. Is it possible to do within the context of `pexpect` however?

Comment: Sure, of course you can also use `pexpect.spawn()`, but just `subprocess` seems cleaner since you're not using any of the interactivity features.